# Child item created two times in ExpandableListView Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, repeat, expandablelistadapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapters extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
List<String> group_data;
List<String> child_data;

public ExpandableListAdapters(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    Log.e("HEADER SIZE", "" + listDataHeader.size() + "..." + listChildData.size());

}

public ExpandableListAdapters(ServicesFragment servicesFragment, List<String> service_names,List<String> service_desc) {
    this._context = servicesFragment.getActivity();
    this.group_data = service_names;
    this.child_data=service_desc;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return child_data.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.e("SERVICE LIST","...."+child_data.get(groupPosition));
    String description = child_data.get(groupPosition);

    //final Double price = data.get(groupPosition).getProducts().get(childPosition).getPrice();
    Log.e("ADAPTER", "........" + description);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    if(!description.equals(null)){
        txtListChild.setText(description);/*+ " : Rs." + price);*/
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return child_data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return group_data.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return group_data.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = group_data.get(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

The above is my code.
Child item is created two times under each group item. 
In my group and child list there are two elements. Actually the expected result for my above code is :

> Group1   child1 Group2   child2

I can't find out the mistake. Please help me anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this getChild method to :

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return child_data.get(groupPosition);
}
```

Correct one :

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
      return child_data.get(group_data.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
}
```

As well,

```
 @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return child_data.get(group_data.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }
```

Comment: shows error " get(int) in List cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)  "

Comment: refer this example - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: in the line  return child_data.get(group_data.get(groupPosition))
                .size();

Answer (score 0):

```
public ExpandableListAdapters(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    Log.e("HEADER SIZE", "" + listDataHeader.size() + "..." + listChildData.size());

}
```

Both fields `group_data` and `child_data` are of type `List<String>`, so you have no information about how many child elements are actually available for each group. You should use the types declared in your constructor. `List<String> group_data;` and `HashMap<String, List<String>>` child_data;`

`HashMap<String, List<String>>`:
The first parameter `String` represents your group element.
The second parameter `List<String>` contains your child elements for this group.

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return child_data.size();
}
```

In this method you have to tell the `ExandableListView`, how many child elements are available for the group at `groupPosition`. So you have to specify how many child elements are available for the group at `groupPosition` :

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return child_data.get(group_data.get(groupPosition)).size();
}
```

Comment: shows error " get(int) in List cannot be applied to (java.lang.String) "

Comment: solved my issue by refering http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/
thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is below. In this you are taking data from **child_data** with index of group position. So for a group , all child have same group position,

```
    @Override
   public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
   return child_data.get(groupPosition);
   }
```

So the code changed to child position.

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
return child_data.get(childPosititon);
}
```

It will help you .

Comment: I have changed the get(groupPostition) to get(childPosition). but no change

Comment: Hi

what is this constructor means?

public ExpandableListAdapters(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    Log.e("HEADER SIZE", "" + listDataHeader.size() + "..." + listChildData.size());

}

Comment: solved my issue by refering http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/
thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Ok daa. This is not the right way of passing data. Put a setter and assign it to global variabale. And invoke notifydatasetchanged() method

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working for you

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) { 
return child_data.get(childPosititon);
}
```

take the first constructor

```
public ExpandableListAdapters(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                         HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
     Log.e("HEADER SIZE", "" + listDataHeader.size() + "..." +         listChildData.size());
```

}

**And Replace the first code**

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) { 
String groupKey=getGroup(groupPosition);
return listChildData.get(groupKey).get(childPosition);
}
```

And also replace the function

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
String groupKey=getGroup(groupPosition);
return listChildData.get(groupKey).size();
}
```

Comment: solved my issue by refering http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/
thank you so much for the help :)